# How to use .fbx for 2D animation in unity 2D

Tags: unity, 2d, fbx

I am new to unity so please bear with me. I have come to know that for animations it is better to fbx format in unity rather than sprite sheets. I am using unity 5.2 and till now i created all my animations inside unity using sprite sheets. I have been looking at fbx and i cant seem to understand how to use the fbx model i imported in a 2d game? All tutorials are for 3D games. Once the fbx is imported , it creates a prefab with all animations in it.. but how to use them ..? Can someone point me to a good tutorial or so..

thanks

Comment: When you talk about using fbx models for 2D game animation, do you mean something like [the process Asteroid Base used for Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime](http://www.asteroidbase.com/devlog/making-friends/) ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, "better" is a relative term. 2D animation (2D games in general, not just in unity) is generally done using spritesheets because they give you the most flexibility. That said, Unity can display any 3D content within a 2D game, so you can use a 3D animation like fbx. That will give you an advatage with interpolation/variable framerates, but at the cost that the appearance of the animation is less flexible.

The thing to realize is that it's still fundamentally a 3D animation, it's just viewed from one side. Thus create the animation in a 3D animation tool, but make it work with a static side view. For example, the 3D parts may actually be planes oriented to face the camera.